# Insert new record(Odoo) - Odoo mobile framework

Tags: android, odoo, odoo-mobile

I have a method which accepts an OValue:

```
getResults(OValues values)
```

Inside the method are the ff.

```
ORecordValues value = new ORecordValues();
value.put("order_partner_id", orderline.getPartner(values));
value.put("product_id", orderline.getProduct(values));
value.put("product_uom_qty",values.getInt("product_uom_qty"));
value.put("price_unit", values.getInt("product_uom_qty"));
value.put("discount",values.getInt("product_uom_qty"));
orderline.getServerDataHelper().createOnServer(value);
```

Is it possible to insert directly to Odoo's server without saving it to android's database?
or any alternative ways to successfully insert data to Odoo server?

In ServerDataHelper java class:

```
public int createOnServer(ORecordValues data) {
  OdooResult result = mOdoo.createRecord(mModel.getModelName(), data);
  return result.getInt("result");
}
```

Comment: What is happening currently when you call createOnServer()?

Comment: there's nothing inserted

Comment: Pl share code of createOnServer() method.

Comment: I updated above and added the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass server record id when creating records on the server.

Pass local row id(stored in *`_id`* column) to the [selectServerId](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/odoo/core/orm/OModel.java#L783) method to get the server id (stored in `id` column):

**Check the following example**:

```
ResPartner resPartner = new ResPartner(getApplicationContext(), null);
ProductProduct productProduct = new ProductProduct(getApplicationContext(), null);

...

ORecordValues value = new ORecordValues();

int partner_id = resPartner.selectServerId(values.getInt("partner_id"));
int product_id = productProduct.selectServerId(values.getInt("product_id"));

value.put("order_partner_id", partner_id);
value.put("product_id", product_id);
value.put("product_uom_qty",values.getInt("product_uom_qty"));
value.put("price_unit", values.getInt("product_uom_qty"));
value.put("discount",values.getInt("product_uom_qty"));

orderline.getServerDataHelper().createOnServer(value);
```